# 'utf8' encoding with list document content

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, scikit-learn

I am getting error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 1266: invalid start byte
```

at line

```
X_train = self.vectorizer.fit_transform(self.data_train.data)
```

So I tried to encode data like this:

```
self.data_train.data = unicode(self.data_train.data, "utf-8")
```

which gives error:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

what is the correct way to perform text encoding here?

code snippet:

```
self.data_train = self.fetch_data(cache, subset='train')
if not os.path.exists(self.root_dir+"/autocreated/vectorizer.txt"):
    self.vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5,
                                     stop_words='english')
    start_time = time()
    print("Transforming the dataset")
    X_train = self.vectorizer.fit_transform(self.data_train.data)  // Error is here
    joblib.dump(self.vectorizer, self.root_dir+"/autocreated/vectorizer.txt")
```

Comment: self.data_train.data.decode('utf8')

Comment: @Farhadix: akready tried it, give error `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found`

Comment: `self.data_train.data = [i.decode('utf-8') for i in self.data_train.data]` you can try this too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're applying `unicode` to a list, but it works on a single string.

```
self.data_train.data = [s.decode("utf-8") for s in self.data_train.data]
```

is the correct syntax; but this is going to break again because the strings aren't valid UTF-8, as scikit-learn has already told you.

You can get `decode` to ignore encoding errors by `s.decode("utf-8", errors='ignore')`, or more easily by letting scikit-learn handle this:

```
TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5, stop_words='english',
                decode_error='ignore')
```

(Although it might be a good idea to revisit your assumption that the input is UTF-8; if it isn't, that can negatively affect your results.)